# How do I test my bootloader on a floppy disk

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system, virtualbox, bootloader

Here is my code: 
http://pastebin.com/pSncVNPK

```
    [BITS 16]           ;Tells the assembler that its a 16 bit code
    [ORG 0x7C00]        ;Origin, tell the assembler that where the code will
                        ;be in memory after it is been loaded

    MOV SI, HelloString ;Store string pointer to SI
    CALL PrintString    ;Call print string procedure
    JMP $       ;Infinite loop, hang it here.


PrintCharacter: ;Procedure to print character on screen     
                ;Assume that ASCII value is in register
    AL MOV AH, 0x0E ;Tell BIOS that we need to print one charater on screen.
    MOV BH, 0x00    ;Page no.
    MOV BL, 0x07    ;Text attribute 0x07 is lightgrey font on black background

    INT 0x10    ;Call video interrupt RET       ;Return to calling procedure



PrintString:    ;Procedure to print string on screen
                ;Assume that string starting pointer is in register SI

next_character: ;Label to fetch next character from string
    MOV AL, [SI]    ;Get a byte from string and store in AL register
    INC SI      ;Increment SI pointer
    OR AL, AL   ;Check if value in AL is zero (end of string)
    JZ exit_function ;If end then return
    CALL PrintCharacter ;Else print the character which is in AL register
    JMP next_character  ;Fetch next character from string
exit_function:  ;End label
    RET     ;Return from procedure


    ;Data
    HelloString db 'Hello World', 0 ;HelloWorld string ending with 0

    TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;Fill the rest of sector with 0
    DW 0xAA55           ;Add boot signature at the end of bootloader
```

As you can see the syntax appears to be correct, compiled it into a .bin file, BUT I'm trying to figure out how to test it. Please treat me like I'm a bit slow because I've spent HOURS googling this topic and nothing seems to work, I've even tried using a hex editor as per some tutorial but it didn't work. This seems to be the closest I've gotten is using these instructions: 
http://puu.sh/6KzUo.png

from this link: [How to make an bootable iso(not cd or flash drive) for testing your own boot loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690300/how-to-make-an-bootable-isonot-cd-or-flash-drive-for-testing-your-own-boot-loa)

Except I don't quite understand step 6 because VM box won't let me select the img file as a bootable disk.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a 5 1/4 inch or 3 1/2 inch floppy?

Comment: @mattingly890 I was trying to use a virtual floppy disk

Comment: Ah, okay. What type of virtual environment are you using?  (VMWare, VirtualBox....)

Comment: @mattingly890 I'm jusing Virtual box, i have ubuntu installed on it as well which is where I compiled the .asm into a .bin

Comment: Have you been able to create the actual .img file (not boot it, but just get it created)?

Comment: @mattingly890 Yeah, i have it: http://puu.sh/6KBp0.jpg

Comment: Have you been able to create a virtual floppy disk controller?

Comment: @mattingly890 is this the controller you're referring to? http://puu.sh/6KBC6.png I'm not sure what to do with it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to add a Floppy Disk into the disk controller, this is how to do it:

Click on the Floppy Controller.  An icon of a floppy with a green plus sign should come up on the left of your selection.  Click on this small icon.

[image]

---

A dialog should now come up:

[image]

Select "Choose Disk"

The file selection box will come up---at this point, choose your `.img` file from the file selection box.

[image]

From this point you should be able to boot the virtual machine from the floppy disk and test your bootloader.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I realized that I messed up and assumed the controller was the floppy disk, I did like you posted and it worked! Thanks

Comment: @oorosco. If this answer works well, consider accepting it and upvoting. Best of luck.