# Boot custom bootloader from usb

Tags: usb, bootloader, iso, dd

I want to boot the iso generated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268518/creating-a-bootable-iso-image-with-custom-bootloader) from usb. I tried

```
sudo dd if=myos.iso of=/dev/sdb count=1
```

Doesn't work. What should I do?
(This image boots in virtualbox)

Comment: Why `count=1` ? By default the size of a block is 512,specifying a count of 1 will only copy the first 512 bytes of `myos.iso` to the USB drive. What happens if you just use `sudo dd if=myos.iso of=/dev/sdb` . This command should copy the entire contest of `myos.iso` to the device.

Comment: I'd also recommend using the `conv=fdatasync` option when writing to a USB device. So I'd use `sudo dd if=myos.iso of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync`

Comment: @Michael Petch doesn't work. I also tried other utilities to no use.

Comment: How about including a proper BPB in the boot sector?