# Create an iso from a .bin file

Tags: assembly, x86, virtual-machine, bin

I created many assembly programs with nasm and I always tested them with qemu (system-x86_64). I would like to create a bootable disk image that I can burn on an USB stick and plug it in my second computer for testing.

For qemu I just needed to make the file end with 0x55aa and make it long 512 bytes.

However I can't seem to find a way to convert my file to a bootable format.

I know that it's better to create a virtual machine using VirtualBox or other software and do my tests in a protected environment to avoid accidental overwriting of files on my SSD drive, but I still face the same problem: VBox only accepts ISO/IMG files (hard drive and floppy).

Comment: Your image should boot fine when block-copied to a USB stick. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @Jester when I put it in my pc it didn't boot

Comment: @Jester also it's just a bin file, not an IMG or ISO file

Comment: You did not just copy it as a file, right? You need to block copy. On linux for example using `dd if=boot.bin of=/dev/sdX`. Replace with the appropriate device. Note it will wipe whatever is on your usb stick.

Comment: @Jester that's the problem. I'm using Windows.

Comment: @Jester I found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690300/how-to-make-an-bootable-isonot-cd-or-flash-drive-for-testing-your-own-boot-loa?rq=2) I was looking for... Thanks for the help!

I used wsl for dd.

Comment: Then you need a program that can copy an image to a USB drive.  https://rufus.ie/en/ is supposed to be good,   Google for `mbr  bootable usb creator for windows` found some others.